# .on('click', .text?

Tags: jquery, click

With the help of this forum great guys (Jai, thanks again), we've come up with the following code:

```
var $someparam = 'is';
$('span').text($someparam);
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Here's the playground: http://jsfiddle.net/DwAAQ/

What the code basically does is takes a variable (="is"), replaces span content with the text from that variable and executes hiding of divs that don't contain the text in the variable on click of this text.
For me, it has two main problems: I can insert spans to the page, can edit css and the code ends up replacing all spans on the page.

The question is: could this code be amended so that it writes text (=$someparam variable, or "is" in the above example) and makes it clickable to execute the jquery? I.e. everything would be contained within this code?

Comment: Not sure I get the question at all, but if you don't want to replace the text in all the spans, why don't you just remove that line? Or if you like to replace the text in all the spans on click, just place it one line down, inside the click function ?

Comment: I want to specify some text (with commas) as a variable. The code then writes it as text on webpage, makes this text clickable and executes the code provided when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to append the span (say for instance to the body), then it should work as that would be the "last" one there.

Example:

```
var $someparam = 'is';
$('body').append('<span>spanner</span>');
$('span :last').text($someparam);
$(document).on('click', 'span :last', function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

EDIT: note this has the same net effect:

```
var $someparam = 'is';
$('body').append('<span>' + $someparam + '</span>');
$(document).on('click', 'span :last', function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

and this is most efficient: with an id

```
var $someparam = 'is';
$('body').append('<span id="myspan">' + $someparam + '</span>');
$('#myspan').on('click', function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

and, use the parameter as a part of the id:

```
var $someparam = 'is';
$('body').append('<span id="myspan' + $someparam + '">' + $someparam + '</span>');
$('#myspan'+ $someparam ).on('click', function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

EDIT2: add example page with working example of each.  This is a bit contrived, but shows each of the above plus one dynamic span added via a button any number of times that is also clickable. (click 1-4, then the new span to see the effect)...

no, id cannot contain a comma, only "letters" in the allowed set (see the html spec) and numbers, and must start with a non-number
http://jsfiddle.net/Cecfu/1/

Comment: Thank's for your input, I'm struggling with appending the lines... I think I'll insert a table and then appendTO('table') .

Comment: Hm, making $someparam a part of the id is great, but alas not workable in this particular case: the variable contains commas. any other ideas? is there really need to add spans or append the bottom of the page? could the text just be placed where the query is and made clickable?

Comment: I've tried the third example. It adds a span with the text from the variable, but it is not clickable. My guess you cannot refer to myspan because it doesn't exist on page?

Comment: @EasyLife - I added an example fiddle with each working and one additional dynamic. Study that :)  Hopefully, this will get you started.

Comment: wow, that's some massive amount of work you did. really appreciate that!

Comment: only took 2 minutes, no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to place a certain text in a certain span (not in all spans) and then on click on one of those spans you want to hide all div.somediv elements that do not contain the text of that div?

Try this

```
$('span#myspan').text('is');
$('span#myotherspan').text('what');
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    var theText = $(this).text();
    $('.somediv').not(':contains("' + theText + '")').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: I started to edit yours and remove mine but it was enough different to just leave it as it was.

Comment: can we avoid spans entirely? The jquery puts .text and makes it clickable?